# Flask: get current blueprint webroot

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am building a Flask app with a blueprint mounted on two different endpoint (one is a legacy alias to the other).

In my blueprint class:

```
ldp = Blueprint('ldp', __name__)

@ldp.route('/<path:uuid>', methods=['GET'])
@ldp.route('/', defaults={'uuid': None}, methods=['GET'],
        strict_slashes=False)

def get_resource(uuid):
    # Route code...
```

In my main server code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(config['flask'])

app.register_blueprint(ldp, url_prefix='/new_ep')
# Legacy endpoint. @TODO Deprecate.
app.register_blueprint(ldp, url_prefix='/old_ep')
```

How can I get the actual URL of the request up to the `/old_ep` or `/new_ep` part in the route method, e.g. `http://localhost:5000/new_ep`?

So far I have used

```
request.host_url + request.path.split('/')[1]
```

but it looks quite inelegant and possibly error-prone. I would like to use the information from the blueprint setup if possible.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I could get to the Blueprint instance from within the request with

```
current_app.blueprints[request.blueprint]
```

and I was hoping that the `url_prefix` attribute that I set when registering the blueprint was there, but it is `None` instead. As I read from the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.iter_blueprints) for the supposedly related `iter_blueprints()` method, apparently these blueprints are listed without regard of how many times and with which parameters they were registered. Too bad.

Comment: Use two different name in `app.register_blueprint("<name>", url_prefix='<url>') `and instantiate accordingly. i.e, `app.register_blueprint(oldep, url_prefix='/old_ep') ` and `oldep =Blueprint("oldep", __name__) for `old_ep` and do same for `new_ep` by replacing in `app.register_blueprint()`. and `oldep.route('/',methods=['GET'])` will route to `http://localhost:5000/old_ep`.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but you can use url defaults to solve this https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/612#issuecomment-15464107

Comment: @GeekSambhu That sounds like a quite involved code change. If I understand, I would have to double all the routes in my blueprint, and if the endpoint is eventually deprecated, I have to remove them? At that point the current solution, although clunky, is just a one-liner.

Comment: @JoshJ Thanks for the suggestion on url defaults, I had not thought about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full working example to get the idea based off [issue 612](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/612#issuecomment-15464107)

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, url_for, request, g

bp = Blueprint('whatever', __name__)

@bp.url_defaults
def bp_url_defaults(endpoint, values):
    url_prefix = getattr(g, 'url_prefix', None)
    if url_prefix is not None:
        values.setdefault('url_prefix', url_prefix)

@bp.url_value_preprocessor
def bp_url_value_preprocessor(endpoint, values):
    g.url_prefix = values.pop('url_prefix')

@bp.route('/something')
def index():
    return 'host prefix is %s%s' % (request.host_url, g.url_prefix)

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/new_ep', url_defaults={'url_prefix': 'new_ep'})
app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/old_ep', url_defaults={'url_prefix': 'old_ep'})
```

[image: Web Output example]

Comment: Thanks @josh-g. In spite of the commentary about "hacks" in the issue this works as I expected.

Comment: I guess the hack part is having to specify it twice instead of accessing the url prefix directly